# What's OBB in android

Tags: android

1. I don't know how to use OBB. Is there any demo?
2. I don't know the advantage of it.
3. Will it throw excepiton when used on the device below android2.3?

Detail:

I've read some articles about it but I still don't know much about it. It seems that people use it just because app size is limitd to 50mb. using it can enlarge it to 4GB. And after I read [*Android Apps Break the 50MB Barrier*](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html) I also think we use it just because it supply `DownloaderClientMarshaller` and some other utils.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB. For most applications, this is plenty of space for all the application's code and assets. However, some apps need more space for high-fidelity graphics, media files, or other large assets. Previously, if your app exceeded 50MB, you had to host and download the additional resources yourself when the user opens the app. Hosting and serving the extra files can be costly, and the user experience is often less than ideal. To make this process easier for you and more pleasant for users, Google Play allows you to attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK.

How to use it-
[See this Link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Comment: that is, if I don't use Google Play, OBB is useless? and ur meaning is that OBB is just a way to enlarge app size?

Comment: Yes, it is useful when you are publishing your app on google play.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is exceeding 50MB (Specially because of the resources) you convert Expansion file to .obb format. This allows you to have

1. apk sizes larger than 50 MB.
2. Google Play allows you to host additional resources for free.
3. This is downloaded along with your apk file( for 99% of time), so you 
   are not required to manage the download from external server.
4. This is used when you have heavy additional resources files usually videos, HD images.I have seen it developers using it while developing games.
5. Its pretty easy and simple.
6. Your app on play store will show the total size, apk size + size of obb file.
7. Play Console takes care of renaming the file. The version number should be same on console and in your configuration file(gradle). You also need to attach the obb file to apk on play console.