# Resizing images at runtime - Android

Tags: android, image-processing, resize

I have 200+ png images in my app.  The highest resolution is 1000 x 1000px (xxhdpi).
The problem is that my apk file size is going way above 50 mb which is the limit. So, I thought of making a single drawable folder. But then on low resolution devices, my images don't look good.

So how can I **Resize images at runtime to fit all the small screen devices**?

If the above is not possible or not a very efficient method, please suggest other ways to effectively reduce the apk size to a considerable extent.

Comment: try this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739574/whats-obb-in-android/17739739#17739739

Comment: @DroidFan why do you want to scale down your images?

Comment: @pskink If I could scale down my images, my apk will be definitely less than 50 mb. As mentioned in the question, I have more than 200 png images. The reason I want to scale them down is that a 1000x1000px image does not look good on a small screen device! This will allow me to use a single drawable folder. Please help me if you have a solution.

Comment: do you use ImaeView to show them or you draw them directly using Canvas.drawBitmap?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Just input your activities' resources, the resource id of your image, the required width and height and this method will return a resized bitmap.

Comment: Thanks Clay! I will definitely try this and let you know

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using the

```
ViewTreeObserver obs = mTv.getViewTreeObserver();
obs.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw () { }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how this will help me solve my problem? Thanks!